# Call Spring Controller method from other method, via the RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a need to call - on the server side - a bunch of Spring Controller methods,  But all I will have is the @RequestMapping value to go on.  Is there any way to do this?

I know this can be done, as it is used in the testing framework via MockMvc.  I want that exact functionality:

```
String a = mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/bar/{id}", foobarId)).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString(); 
String b = mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/car/{id}", foobarId)).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString(); 
String totals = a + b;
```

And quite frankly I was thinking of using this as it seems to do exactly what I want it to do. Would there be a problem using this? I just autowire the WebApplicationContext into the controller and that will work. Right? :)

**EDIT**

The redirect is not what I want.  I don't want to chain calls, and every call must also be able to be used by the web browser as a standalone method as well

**UPDATE**

It occurs to me that when spring starts up, it does a component scan, looks for @Controllers  and @RequestMapping  and must make a Map of some sort to map URL class.method()   Right?  It won't scan all the classes for each call.  The question is,  where is this map once it's scanned and loaded,  and can a mere developer of controllers get access to it?

Comment: Can't use JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: No.  Server Side mandate on this one.

Comment: Then try RestTemplate https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `redirect`, like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar/{foobarId}")
public String testView (@PathVariable("foobarId") String foobarId) {
    return "any view";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "test")
public String test (String msg) {
    String foobarId = .....;
    return "redirect:/foo/bar/" + foobarId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a total hack,  but totally works:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/TEST")
public class TestController {

private MockMvc mockMvc;
private WebApplicationContext wbctx = null;
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

public void init() {
    if(wbctx==null) {
        wbctx =  WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wbctx).build();
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@ResponseBody
public String testme() throws Exception {
    init();
    String a =  mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/bar/{id}", 1)).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();  
    String b =  mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/car/{id}", 1)).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();  
    return a+b;
}
}
```